# How to use Riverpod with SearchAnchor correctly?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, material3, riverpod-generator

I have a problem when I try to use Riverpod with a SearchAnchor from Material 3. The SearchAnchor didn't return the correct suggestions while I typed new text.

I have implemented a StateProvider and ref.watch in build method to update UI.

[demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OoKkbssV-ikwoMva3zjC207hiAXI2jbx/view?usp=sharing)

```
final searchProvider = StateProvider((ref) => '');

@riverpod
Stream<List<String>> suggestions(SuggestionsRef ref) async* {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 250));
  final query = ref.watch(searchProvider);
  final noteUseCase = await ref.watch(noteUseCaseProvider.future);
  yield* noteUseCase.getNoteSuggestions(query: query);
}

@riverpod
Stream<List<AddedNote>> notes(NotesRef ref) async* {
  ref.state = const AsyncValue.loading();
  final notes = await ref.watch(
      noteUseCaseProvider.selectAsync((noteUseCase) => noteUseCase.notes));
  yield* notes;
}
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchController = SearchController()
      ..addListener(() {
        ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).state = _searchController.text;
      });
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final noteState = ref.watch(notesProvider);
    final suggestionState = ref.watch(suggestionsProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  sliver: SliverAppBar(
                    forceMaterialTransparency: true,
                    collapsedHeight: 70.0,
                    floating: true,
                    flexibleSpace: SearchAnchor(
                      searchController: _searchController,
                      isFullScreen: false,
                      suggestionsBuilder: (_, controller) => suggestionState.when(
                        data: (suggestions) => suggestions.map(
                          (suggestion) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(suggestion),
                            onTap: () => controller.closeView(suggestion),
                          ),
                        ),
                        error: (_, __) => [],
                        loading: () => [],
                      ),
                      builder: (context, controller) => SearchBar(
                        hintText: 'Search title, content',
                        hintStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll<TextStyle?>(
                          Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                                color:
                                    Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                              ),
                        ),
                        controller: controller,
                        padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 16.0),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => controller.openView(),
                        onChanged: (_) => controller.openView(),
                        leading: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                        ),
                        trailing: const [Icon(Icons.search)],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  sliver: SliverGrid(
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                    ),
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, index) => noteState.whenOrNull(
                        skipError: true,
                        skipLoadingOnRefresh: true,
                        skipLoadingOnReload: true,
                        data: (notes) => MobileNoteItem(
                          key: ObjectKey(notes[index]),
                          note: notes[index],
                          onTap: () => context.go(
                            '${NavDestination.home.path}/${notes[index].id}',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      childCount:
                          noteState.whenOrNull(data: (notes) => notes.length) ?? 0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            if (noteState.isLoading)
              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context
            .go('${NavDestination.home.path}/${NavDestination.write.path}'),
        tooltip: 'Write',
        child: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      ),
    );
```

info:

flutter version: 3.13.4
flutter_riverpod version: 2.4.0
Any help or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I've fixed it, using Consumer inside viewBuilder.